# How to extract valid string from beginning to the first no base64 valid character?

Tags: python, python-2.7, base64

I have base64 encoded string but at the end sometimes appears some trailing garbage which always start with no valid base64 character. How to extract valid string from beginning to the first no base64 valid character ?

For example:

```
data = "(there  is more valid content)gw3AQEFGh8NFgoqDwYsAQALDVFPVltYVkNGXldCRFUbNRk=----------:jhawrewre:--\r\n"
```

and valid part would be without `"----------:jhawrewre:--\r\n"`

```
valid = "(there  is more valid content)gw3AQEFGh8NFgoqDwYsAQALDVFPVltYVkNGXldCRFUbNRk="
```

Comment: some example input would be nice...

Comment: @FredrikPihl I have added example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to remove the invalid portion:

```
import re

invalid_tail = re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9+/=\n\r].*$')

def remove_tail(base64_value):
    return invalid_tail.sub('', base64_value)
```

The `[^a-zA-Z0-9+/=\n\r]` matches any character that is *not* a valid Base64 character, plus the trailing `=` padding and newlines and carriage returns (which are allowed in encoded values to wrap lines).

Demo:

```
>>> example = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog!'.encode('base64')
>>> remove_tail(example + '*This is a tail').decode('base64')
'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog!'
```

or, using the decodable portion of your sample:

```
>>> data = "3AQEFGh8NFgoqDwYsAQALDVFPVltYVkNGXldCRFUbNRk=----------:jhawrewre:--\r\n"
>>> remove_tail(data).decode('base64')
'\xdc\x04\x04\x14h|4X(\xa8<\x18\xb0\x04\x00,5E=YmaY\r\x19y]\t\x11Tl\xd4d'
```

This solution easily beats the `itertools.takewhile()` option on speed:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> text = "gw3AQEFGh8NFgoqDwYsAQALDVFPVltYVkNGXldCRFUbNRk=----------:jhawrewre:--\r\n"
>>> timeit.timeit('test(text)', 'from __main__ import with_takewhile as test, text')
11.785380125045776
>>> timeit.timeit('test(text)', 'from __main__ import with_re as test, text')
1.480334997177124
```

Using a regular expression is almost 10 times faster for this simple sample; for longer text the results will be faster still.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: no, it accidentally gained an erroneous opening `(` instead. :-) (Thanks).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.takewhile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

> Make an iterator that returns elements from the iterable as long as
>   the `predicate` is true.

**Demo:**

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> from string import letters,digits
>>> valid_chars = letters + digits + '+/='
>>> text = "gw3AQEFGh8NFgoqDwYsAQALDVFPVltYVkNGXldCRFUbNRk=----------:jhawrewre:--\r\n"
>>> "".join(takewhile(lambda x:x in valid_chars, text))
'gw3AQEFGh8NFgoqDwYsAQALDVFPVltYVkNGXldCRFUbNRk='
```

Comment: Wow, this is a really slow solution; I expected `re` to be able to beat `takewhile()` but I get a nearly 10x difference..

Comment: @MartijnPieters Totally agree, `re` is the better solution here.